# Highcharts chart going blank on compare : 'percent' and type: 'arearange'

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart displaying data correctly in a datarange; but the moment I add another series and set compare to percent it goes blank.

```
$(function () {
// Notice that the dataset has missing data
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=range.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
            type: 'areasplinerange'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                **compare: 'percent'**
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: data
        }]

    });
});
});
```

You could see a sample here:
[Test sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nrbcLbgj/3/)

Comment: Anything in console?

Comment: @HalvorStrand  no,it doesnt show any thing is console.but my y axis shows percent values .and it shows other series when i remove the arearange serie.

Comment: Doesn't seem like your code sample is complete?

Comment: @TZHX i didn't add the whole code.the data part is okay.i'm not sure about the chart setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported that as possibly bug in our tracker here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4922